# Android ViewModelProvider.of() cannot find symbol

Tags: android, android-studio, viewmodel

I tried to get my custom ViewModel 'ViewModelSavegame' with the ViewModelProvider to set a Observer.

```
viewModelSavegame = ViewModelProvider.of(this).get(ViewModelSavegame.class);
        viewModelSavegame.GetSavegameName().observe(this, new Observer<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(String s)
            {
                TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTitel);
                title.setText(s);
            }
        });
```

In the Gradle build (module:app) I have dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.2.0"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

But ViewModelProvider.***of***() create the error:

error: cannot find symbol
        viewModelSavegame = ViewModelProvider.of(this).get(ViewModelSavegame.class);
                                             ^
  symbol:   method of(SavegameTabbedActivity)

Did I missed something maybe a dependencie?

Answer (score 0):

Change the code from ViewModelProvider.of(this).get(ViewModelSavegame.class) to ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModelSavegame.class).

Comment: This result in "need method call" and Android Studio want me to change it to:
new ViewModelProvider.of(this).get(ViewModelSavegame.class)
I don't think thats correct but I'm not sure.

Comment: Does your ViewModelSaveGame class have any arguments in constructor?

Comment: public ViewModelSavegame(@NonNull Application application)
    {
        super(application);
}

Comment: Does you class extend AndroidViewModel or ViewModel?

Comment: AndroidViewModel

Comment: Okay then, this code should work ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(application).create(ViewModelSavegame.class)

Comment: This is because if there are any args defined in viewmodel constructor then we need to create our own custom viewmodel factory. When using AndroidViewModel we could use AndroidViewModelFactory to pass the application to the viewmodel

Comment: viewModelSavegame = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(getApplication()).create(ViewModelSavegame.class);
This is exactly the same: Method call expected -> insert new. But this will crash the app.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Use
`viewModelSavegame = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(getApplication()).create(ViewModelSavegame.class);`

Maybe someone can provide further information, but of() seems to be replaced with getInstance(). 
I hope this is the correct way to use this in an TabbedActivity and their fragments to provide the same view model, but at least it works, without crashing the app.